# Link redirect to contact form with individual subject

Tags: jquery, forms, contacts, subject

What I want to do is this: somebody clicks a button and will then be taken to a new page with a contact form with an individual subject. So the link needs to provide the subject in a way such as

To be more precise, clicking on :

```
button 1 = contact form with subject 1
button 2 = contact form with subject 2
button n = contact form with subject n
```

As this is running on Wordpress it would be great if that could be used with a popular plugin such as Contact Form 7.

Has anybody done similar or is able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: You mean the content of subject text area should change depending on button? And what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```html
<input value="subject 1" type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('ta').value='subject 1'">
<input value="subject 2" type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('ta').value='subject 2'">
<br>
<form>
    <textarea id="ta"></textarea>
</form>
```

If you want to redirect to another page with this form, you can use hash, for example:

1st page (subject picker)

```
<body>
    <input value="subject 1" type="button" onclick="window.location.href='http://example.com/form#subject1'">
    <input value="subject 2" type="button" onclick="window.location.href='http://example.com/form#subject2'">
</body>
```

2nd page (with form)

```
<body onload="var hash=window.location.hash;if(hash=='#subject1'){document.getElementById('ta').value='Subject 1';}if(hash=='#subject2'){document.getElementById('ta').value='Subject 2';}">
    <form>
        <textarea id="ta"></textarea>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Is the contact form on the same page? I got the impression it was linking to a page with a contact form on. OP?

Comment: Contact form is on a separate page - have improved the original question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the value of the text box with the given subject using jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("button").click(function () {
    $("#subject").val($(this).data("subject"));
  });
});
```

```css
form {display: block; margin: 10px 0;}
form ul {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
form ul li {list-style: none; margin: 10px 0;}
textarea {display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-subject="Hello, World!">World</button>
<button data-subject="Hello, Earth!">Earth</button>

<form action="">
  <ul>
    <li>Subject: <input type="text" id="subject" /></li>
    <li>Message: <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></li>
    <li><input type="submit" /></li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could add a http get style value to the link, i.e.

```
<a href="http://somelinek.com?subject=Hi this is my subject">Click</a>
```

Be aware you'd be best to url encode and you'll have to get the value from the url (window.location etc) and inject it into the value of your input on load.

It's also gonna be visible so should only be used on non-sensitive information.

If you don't want it in the url you could always use local/session storage